# Livewire checkbox selecting items on previous page for a paginated page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Please help, I'm currently working on this livewire project. The page is paginated with checkboxes. When I check boxes on the next page, it reloads the data on the first page and selects another item of the same number in the row. So if try to select a checkbox of row 3 on the second page, data will refresh to show items of previous page, and select the checkbox of row 3
I'm unable to figure it out, someone please help.

Below is my code

```
    {
        $tracking_dates = Tracking::select(DB::raw('max(created_at) as created_at'))
            ->groupBy('tracking_number')
            ->get();
        $this->trackings = Tracking::query()
            ->when(Auth::user()->hasRole('user'), function($query){
                $query->whereHas('PurchaseRequest', function($sub_query) {
                    $sub_query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id());
                });
            })
            ->whereIn('created_at', $tracking_dates)
            ->paginate(20);

        return view('livewire.index-tracker', [
                'trackings' => $this->trackings,
                'trackingStatus' => TrackingStatus::all(),
            ]);
    }
```

My view Code

````
                <form>
                <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @role('superadministrator')
                        <th>Multiple Action Select</th>
                        @endrole
                        <th>Item(s) Type</th>
                        <th>Tracking Number</th>
                        <th>Tracking Status</th>
                        <th>Invoice</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>


                    <tbody>
                        @if(count($trackings) > 0)
                            @foreach($trackings as $key=>$tracking)
                                <tr>
                                    @role('superadministrator')
                                    <td>
                                        {{$tracking->id}}
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{$tracking->id}}" wire:model="selected">
                                    </td>
                                    @endrole
                                    <td>
                                        {{$tracking->purchase_request_id != "" ? "Purchase Request" : NULL}}
                                        {{$tracking->shipment_id != "" ? "Shipment" : NULL}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{$tracking->tracking_number}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$tracking->TrackingStatus->name}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{route('purchase_request.show',$tracking->PurchaseRequest->invoice_no)}}"><i class="mdi mdi-eye font-18"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{route('tracking.show', $tracking->tracking_number)}}" class="m-r-15 text-muted" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View Tracking Detail" data-original-title="View Tracking Invoice"><i class="mdi mdi-eye font-18"></i></a>
{{--                                        @role('superadministrator')--}}
                                        <a href="{{route('tracking.edit', $tracking->tracking_number)}}" class="m-r-15 text-muted" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil font-18"></i></a>
{{--                                        @endrole--}}
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        @else
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5">No data available</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                @role('superadministrator')
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <button wire:click.prevent="store()" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Track</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                @if(count($trackings) > 0)
                    {{ $trackings->links() }}
                @endif```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can call the javascript page.dt() event and store all ids you have checked into local storage.
Please refer below code for that.

```
var checkedData = [];
$('#tableID').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    let allIds = localStorage.getItem("row-data-ids").split(",");

    $('.checkboxes:checkbox:checked').each(function(index, rowId){
        if($.inArray( $(this).val(),  allIds) ==  -1){
            checkedData.push($(this).val());
        }

    });
    localStorage.setItem('row-data-ids', checkedData);
} );
```

You can also store local storage values to hidden variable to get into POST Request.

Comment: Thanks, but first I'm using livewire that does the binding for me, also your solution assumes I'm using data-table which I am until now, but I have removed the data table, and it's the page content that refreshes.